# Image not show at Recyclerview using Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-glide

I have a list of a post using recyclerview. The list are great, but problem come when I try to add an image at the recyclerview. I'm using Glide to add the images. I have successed adding image using glide at Navigation Drawer, but when i try at Recyclerview it show nothing than the default image i sourced.

This is **my kotlin**,

```
class InformationListActivity : MainActivity() {
private val glide: RequestManager? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_list)

    val toolbar = findViewById<View>(R.id.toolbar) as Toolbar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar!!.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)

    val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    val uName = user?.displayName
    val uEmail = user?.email
    val uPhotoUrl = user?.photoUrl
    user?.uid

    val navigationView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nav_view) as NavigationView
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    val headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0)

    val navName = headerView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.navName)
    navName.text = uName
    val navEmail = headerView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.navEmail)
    navEmail.text = uEmail
    val navImage = headerView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.navImage)
    Glide.with(this).load(uPhotoUrl).into(navImage)

    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)

    val signOut = findViewById<View>(R.id.btnSignOut) as LinearLayout
    signOut.setOnClickListener {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()
        val goToLogin = Intent(this@InformationListActivity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(goToLogin)
    }


    val recyclerView = findViewById<View>(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("/posts")
    val recyclerAdapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, InformationListActivity.PostViewHolder>(
            Post::class.java,
            R.layout.information_model,
            InformationListActivity.PostViewHolder::class.java,
            myref
    ) {
        override fun populateViewHolder(viewHolder: InformationListActivity.PostViewHolder, model: Post, position: Int) {
            val data_empty = findViewById<View>(R.id.data_empty) as TextView
            data_empty.visibility = View.GONE
            viewHolder.run {
                glide?.let { setmPostImageUrl(it,model.getmPostImageUrl()) }
                setmPostTitle(model.getmPostTitle())
                setmPostDescription(model.getmPostDescription())
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(object : ItemClickListener {
                    override fun onItemClick(pos: Int) {
                        //OPEN DETAIL ACTIVITY
                        openInformationDetail(model.getmPostImageUrl(), model.getmPostTitle(), model.getmPostDescription())
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
}

private fun openInformationDetail(vararg details: String) {
    val i = Intent(this, InformationDetailActivity::class.java)
    i.putExtra("POSTIMAGEURL_KEY", details[0])
    i.putExtra("POSTTITLE_KEY", details[1])
    i.putExtra("POSTDESCRIPTION_KEY", details[2])
    startActivity(i)
}

class PostViewHolder(mView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView), View.OnClickListener {
    private var modelImgPost: ImageView = mView.findViewById(R.id.imgPost)
    private var modelPostTitle: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.modelPostTitle)
    private var modelPostDescription: TextView = mView.findViewById(R.id.modelPostDescription)
    private var btnMore: Button = mView.findViewById(R.id.btnMore)
    private lateinit var itemClickListener: ItemClickListener

    init {
        btnMore.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    fun setItemClickListener(itemClickListener: ItemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        this.itemClickListener.onItemClick(this.layoutPosition)
    }

    fun setmPostImageUrl(glide: RequestManager, mPostImageUrl: String) {
        glide.load(Uri.parse(mPostImageUrl)).into(modelImgPost)
    }

    fun setmPostTitle(mPostTitle: String) {
        modelPostTitle.text = mPostTitle
    }

    fun setmPostDescription(mPostDescription: String) {
        modelPostDescription.text = mPostDescription
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't store Glide in an Activity field. You can get Glide at use site like so: `Glide.with(modelImgPost)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (glide != null) {
    setmPostImageUrl(glide, model.getmPostImageUrl())
}
```

Glide is **null** because you never assign / instantiate it.

Replace this line:

```
private val glide: RequestManager? = null
```

with:

```
private var glide: RequestManager? = null
```

and in `onCreate()` do:

```
glide = Glide.with(this)
```

Comment: @EMFarih Update the code in the question to what you have now.

Comment: @EMFarih You've replaced the if null check with a slightly different null check (let). 
You glide object is still null and thus never used to load an image.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Ascorbin Why not `private lateinit var glide: ReuestManager` and avoid the null check?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Would have been possible too of course (and probably the better variant). Just wanted to change his code as little as possible to focus on the actual problem (glide being null).